# How to run VirtualEnvActivate from inside .vimrc

Tags: vim, virtualenv

I am able to run it inside vim from the colon prompt.

When I put the same inside .vimrc, I get:

E492: Not an editor command: VirtualEnvActivate black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are loaded after `.vimrc` (`:help startup`). Use `autocmd VimEnter *` in `.vimrc` to set up commands to run later (`:help :autocmd`, `:help :augroup`, `:help VimEnter`):

```
augroup SetUpVirtualEnv
  au!
  au VimEnter * VirtualEnvActivate black
augroup END
```